# How to compare two python files with the same name in different branches in GitHub?

Tags: python, github, compare, branch

I have 2 versions of a Python code (python files with the same name) in 2 different branches in GitHub.

How can I compare these files in GitHub?

I am aware of `git diff` command but I am looking for a way to compare files in the repository user interface (instead of using git commands in the terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the branches which will show any diffs:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/compare/branchA...branchB
```